# Mac spoofing for virtual machine to trick my university's IT system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, mac-address

I need help in setting up Oracle's VirtualBox port forwarding and/or mac spoofing. I feel it's important to add that my knowledge is very limited in this field and that my question could even be incorrectly defined.

At my university, one has to register their mac address to gain access to the internet. I have registered my computer and my internet connection is working. However, when I run a virtual machine (VM) session and try to access the internet through the VM, the network cuts my connection. My understanding is that it's due to the mac address on the VM being different to the mac address on my computer (the host).

I have tried reading many links, such as the [Oracle manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward). However, the stuff mentioned is beyond my knowledge level. I don't understand the difference between concepts like NAT, port forwarding and bridged adaptor.

So basically, I am looking for a way to somehow get the VM mac address to match the host mac address.

**What I have tried so far:**

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images. A snapshot of my screen looks like [this](http://minecraft.codeemo.com/mineoswiki/index.php?title=File:Virtualbox_vm_settings_network.png). I have entered my host mac address into the mac address field (as seen in the image).

My university uses a web page to sign into the internet. I have entered my login details on my the host side and tried to access the internet from the guest side. It did't work.

Then I tried to enter login details on both the host and guest side, but to no avail.

**EDIT:**
I originally incorrectly posted the question in stack overflow (I apologise). However, significant progress was made. I can now even install windows updates in the VM, but strangely enough I can't launch a website in my browser (Chrome).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select NAT. NAT stands for Network Address Translation. In this case, it will make all traffic from the VM appear to originate from your host system.

Unless you need incoming connections to your guest system you should be fine with this.

Comment: +1. @user2758991 Also because having the same MAC in the host and the guest in *bridged mode* will get you the same IP from the DHCP server - which can create undesirable effects.

Comment: Thanks. I have set it to NAT, but it still did not work.

Comment: I originally incorrectly posted the question in stack overflow (I apologise). However, there is a chain of interesting comments showing the progress of what has been done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047491/mac-spoofing-for-virtual-machine-to-trick-my-universitys-it-system?noredirect=1#comment35216623_23047491

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the previous answer was correct.

But the real problem I experienced was due to the VM being set to use a proxy when connecting to the internet.